# VBA - Need to parse a 2nd column and tack to the bottom, but stuck

Tags: excel, vba

Currently have a dataset like the below... 'For Each Item In Split(.Cells(rw, 4), ",") 'split the string for risk from ","

[image]

I can parse the "data 1" column successfully, but it stops and I can't figure out for the life of me why.. I thought the Next col would push it to "data 2" and start sliding it below the last row. Help?!

which leaves me with this..

[image: which leaves me with this..]

BUT! I want this...

[image: BUT! I want this...]
Sub splt()

```
Dim i As Long, rw As Long, col As Long, rwCnt As Long, colCnt As Long

i = 2
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Cells(1, 7) = "Category"
    .Cells(1, 8) = "Subcategory"
    .Cells(1, 9) = "Notes"
    .Cells(1, 10) = "Label"
    .Cells(1, 11) = "Rank"

    rwCnt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last non-empty row number for labels & words
    colCnt = .Cells(.Columns.Count, 1).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last non-empty column for columns
    For col = 1 To colCnt 'from column 1 til last non-emty column
        For rw = 2 To rwCnt 'from row 1 til last non-empty row
                If .Cells(rw, col) <> "" Then ' 'if the splitted part of the string is not empty
                    .Cells(i, 7) = .Cells(rw, 1) 'populate column 7 with column 1
                    .Cells(i, 8) = .Cells(rw, 2)   'populate column 8 with column 2
                    .Cells(i, 9) = .Cells(rw, 3) 'populate column 9 with column 3
                    .Cells(i, 10) = Split(.Cells(rw, col), ",") 'populate low with splitted part of the string
                    .Cells(i, 11) = "Low"
                    .Cells((rwCnt + i), 10) = Split(.Cells(rw, col), ",") 'add med to bottom of low
                    .Cells((rwCnt + i), 11) = "Med"
                    'need to add high to bottom of med (??rwCnt*2 + i )??
                    i = i + 1 ' increase i variable by one to be able to write the next empty row for the next loop
                End If
        Next rw
    Next col
End With

'.Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.Delete 'when all data is extracted, delete

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what your expected outcome is.  A screenshot would help here, plus including worksheet column/row headers in the "before" screenshot helps tie your code to the data.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I can't get the macro to work or provide the full context haha. Updated just now for full context. I hope that helps. As for the original it's the first column/first row start but I updated it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw As Long, rwOut As Long, arr, col As Long, v, e
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    
    ws.Cells(1, 8).Resize(1, 5).Value = _
          Array("Category", "SubCat", "Notes", "Label", "Rank")
    
    rwOut = 2
    For col = 4 To 6
        For rw = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            v = ws.Cells(rw, col).Value
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                arr = Split(v, ",")
                For Each e In arr
                    'Cat, subcat & notes
                    ws.Cells(rwOut, 8).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                                     ws.Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value
                    
                    ws.Cells(rwOut, 11).Value = Trim(e)

                    ws.Cells(rwOut, 12).Value = _
                                     Array("Low", "Med", "High")(col - 4)

                    rwOut = rwOut + 1
                Next e
            End If
        Next rw
    Next col

End Sub
```

Comment: Ahhh! I wasn't setting a range correctly and the arrays are a nice tough. I think I'm connecting the dots! Thank you!

Comment: Also my columns were messed up... smh